# Google App Engine: How to serve uploaded images in a PHP loop from google cloud storage

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have been using PHP Codeigniter Framework hosted on Google App Engine Platform.

As we know due to security reason Google does not allow to upload images as same as general platform. So I used Google Cloud Storage to upload images and I have successfully implemented it by creating a septate library in Codeigniter.

Problem I am having is how to server them in a foreach or for loop. If I call image once than it displayed on the web page but if I tries to implement that code in a loop it halts when loop counter goes to second count. Below is the library and Helper function I created and calling in a loop.

**Library:**

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

class Display {

    var $config = Array();
    var $image_url = '';
    var $folder = '';
    var $image  = '';
    var $size   = 400;
    var $crop = true;

    public function __construct(){
        $bucket = CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName();
        $this->image_url = 'gs://' . $bucket . '/uploads/';
    }

    public function image_url(){
        $path = $this->image_url.$this->folder.'/';
        $this->image_url  = ( !empty($this->image) &&  is_file( $path . $this->image)) ?$path .$this->image:'noimage_thb.png' ;
        $image_url = @CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($this->image_url);
        /*printArray($this->image_url,1);*/
        if($image_url == ''){
            $image_url = '';
        }

        return $image_url;
    }
}

?>
```

**Helper Function:**

```
if (!function_exists('image_url')) {
    function image_url($folderName,$image, $size, $crop = false)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // we first load the upload library
        $CI->load->library('display');
        $CI->display->folder = $folderName;
        $CI->display->image = $image;
        $CI->display->size = $size;
        $CI->display->crop = $crop;
        $url = $CI->display->image_url();
        return $url;
    }
}
```

**View File Code(Loop):**

```
<div class="fotorama" data-allowfullscreen="true" data-nav="thumbs">
    <?php
            $images = explode(",", $dbdata['beach_photo']);
            for ($img_no = 0; $img_no < count($images); $img_no++) {
                $imageUrl = image_url('venue', $images[$img_no], '400');
    ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
 <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

***Please leave your answers if anyone faced same issue.***

Comment: any error or there is any output??

Comment: @Abdulla Yes, I am getting error in console but not on the page.

I am getting "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://*******.appspot.com/venue/venueDetailes/elements-mall-jaipur"

It comes when file does not exists but I cross checked file is there and also displayed when I print a secong key element of $images array.

Comment: issue is with your URL or in data which you are passing

Comment: @Abdulla I think it is not as I individual executed each url generated for image initialized in $image array.

$images = explode(",", $dbdata['beach_photo']);

in this variable I am getting 0 to 2 Array index value and I executed for all three elements.

If I execute single call it does not give any error but whenever I make multiple call it gives error in Console and PHP script get halt and does not execute remaining script.

Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As I didn't get any solution from anybody so I dug into my code step by step and found solution.**
Error I was getting due to incorrect path generation at the time basic helper function called in loop. So here are the updated version which can be usable. Putting my answer here as I didn't find Google Cloud examples in OOPs concept or in library form.

**Library: (Display.php)**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

class Display
{

    public $config = Array();
    public $image_url = '';
    public $folder = '';
    public $image = '';
    public $size = 400;
    public $path = '';
    public $crop = true;
    public $bucket = '';

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @access    public
     */
    public function __construct($props = array())
    {
        $this->bucket = CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName();
        if (count($props) > 0) {
            $this->initialize($props);
        }

        log_message('debug', "Upload Class Initialized");
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Initialize preferences
     *
     * @param    array
     * @return    void
     */
    public function initialize($config = array())
    {
        $defaults = array(
            'folder' => 0,
            'image' => 0,
            'size' => 600,
            'crop' => false
        );
        foreach ($defaults as $key => $val) {
            if (isset($config[$key])) {
                $method = 'set_' . $key;
                if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                    $this->$method($config[$key]);
                } else {
                    $this->$key = $config[$key];
                }
            } else {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }

        $this->image_url = 'gs://' . $this->bucket . '/uploads/';
    }

    public function set_image($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function set_folder($folder)
    {
        $this->folder = $folder;
    }

    public function set_crop($n)
    {
        $this->crop = $n;
    }

    public function set_size($n)
    {
        $this->size = (int) $n;
    }

    public function image_url()
    {
        $this->path = $this->image_url . $this->folder . '/';
        /*printArray($this->size.' AND '.$this->crop,1);*/
        $this->image_url = (!empty($this->image) && is_file($this->path . $this->image)) ? $this->path . $this->image : $this->path . 'noimage_thb.png';
        $image_url = @CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($this->image_url, ['size' => (int) $this->size, 'crop' => $this->crop]);
        if ($image_url == '') {
            $image_url = '';
        }
        return $image_url;
    }

    public function delete_image()
    {
        $this->path = $this->image_url . $this->folder . '/';
        /*printArray($this->size.' AND '.$this->crop,1);*/
        $this->image_url = (!empty($this->image) && is_file($this->path . $this->image)) ? $this->path . $this->image : $this->path . 'noimage_thb.png';
        $image_url = @CloudStorageTools::deleteImageServingUrl($this->image_url);
        return $image_url;
    }

}

?>
```

**Helper:**

```
if (!function_exists('image_url')) {
    function image_url($folderName, $image, $size, $crop = false)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // we first load the upload library
        $CI->load->library('display');
        $config['folder'] = $folderName;
        $config['size'] = $size;
        $config['crop'] = $crop;
        $config['image'] = $image;
        $CI->display->initialize($config);
        $url = $CI->display->image_url($image);
        return $url;
    }
}
```

**View: *(How to use)***

```
<?php

$images = explode(",", $dbdata['beach_photo']);

for ($img_no = 0; $img_no < count($images); $img_no++) {

$imageUrl = image_url('venue', $images[$img_no], '1200', true);

?>

<img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" class="img-responsive"/>

<?php

}

?>
```

Hope this post may help to Google Developers. More about me you can find here [www.iamabhishek.com](http://www.iamabhishek.com)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, problem was here in my library:

```
    $path = $this->image_url.$this->folder.'/';
     $this->image_url  = 
( !empty($this->image) &&  is_file($path .$this->image)) ?$path.$this->image:'noimage_thb.png' ;
```

every time when loop executes and create image path first time that time image path created is right but after first indexing whenever path make generates it was not replacing previous generated path instead of it was appending older path variable.

I will post proper solution soon. With new version of library.